# Sort aray of objects by another array of objects reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need some help to sort this data out, i have an array of products and i need to sort and display by settings configuration. The output must have the same order as settings array (index) and if display is true. Thanks in advance. This is what i tryed:

```js
var products = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Chocolate', category: 'Sweet'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Almendras', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Nueces', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Mermelada', category: 'Jam'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Alfajor', category: 'Sweet'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Queso', category: 'UwU'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Arandanos', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 7, name: 'Maracuya', category: 'Fruit'}
];

let settings = [
    {
        name: 'Fruit',
        display: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Jam',
        display: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Sweet',
        display: true
    },
    {
        name: 'UwU',
        display: true
    }
]


let group = products.reduce((r, a) => {
      r[a.category] = [...r[a.category] || [], a];
      return r;
    }, {});

let arrangedProducts = Object.keys(group); 

console.log(group);
console.log(arrangedProducts);
```

This is my expected output:

```js
/*
expected result = [
    [
        {id: 1, name: 'Almendras', category: 'Fruit'}, 
        {id: 2, name: 'Nueces', category: 'Fruit'}, 
        {id: 6, name: 'Arandanos', category: 'Fruit'},
        {id: 7, name: 'Maracuya', category: 'Fruit'}
    ],
    [
        {id: 0, name: 'Chocolate', category: 'Sweet'},
        {id: 4, name: 'Alfajor', category: 'Sweet'}
    ],
    [
        {id: 5, name: 'Queso', category: 'UwU'}
    ]
]
*/
```

Comment: I’d say this is “grouping” not sorting.

Comment: See [*Group array elements depending on their value*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209062/group-array-elements-depending-on-their-value) and [*How to group and sort object array?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979068/how-to-group-and-sort-object-array)

Comment: Your `settings` array is never being used, that might be some part of your problem.

Comment: You might first want to parse the *settings* array into an object of `{name: display}` so that the values are easier to access, or build an index object of `{name: index}` so you don't have to iterate the array every time to find out whether a particular name should be displayed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your `settings` list based on the `display` property and then use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return a list of objects in `products` that match the category:

```js
const products = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Chocolate', category: 'Sweet'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Almendras', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Nueces', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Mermelada', category: 'Jam'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Alfajor', category: 'Sweet'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Queso', category: 'UwU'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Arandanos', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 7, name: 'Maracuya', category: 'Fruit'}
];

const settings = [
    { name: 'Fruit', display: true },
    { name: 'Jam', display: false },
    { name: 'Sweet', display: true },
    { name: 'UwU', display: true }
];

const result = settings
  .filter(c => c.display)
  .map(c => products.filter(o => o.category == c.name));

console.log(result);
```

Note that this code does filter the `products` array for each `settings` value that has `display:true`, so may be slow for large arrays. However `filter` is pretty low overhead and testing with OP's sample data shows this to run 3x the speed of the `reduce` version; and with a larger `products` array (99 entries) to run 10x faster.

Comment: Cool use of *filter*, but it runs it once for every element in the filtered *settings* array so might have performance considerations with large data sets. :-)

Comment: @RobG agreed, for big data sets processing the data only once will definitely work better. But I suspect that's a reasonably big number because there should be less overhead in filter compared to reduce.

Comment: @RobG fyi, I timed this and the most upvoted answer's code for OPs sample data, and this code runs almost 3x faster

Comment: @RobG with a larger products array (99 elements) this code ran more than 10x faster than the other answer

Comment: I think it's a good answer (you got my vote!), I just think it needs that caveat. The "most upvoted answer" is code–only so no vote from me.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

1. Making of groups
2. Apply settings and retrieve the result

```js
const products = [
  { id: 0, name: "Chocolate", category: "Sweet" },
  { id: 1, name: "Almendras", category: "Fruit" },
  { id: 2, name: "Nueces", category: "Fruit" },
  { id: 3, name: "Mermelada", category: "Jam" },
  { id: 4, name: "Alfajor", category: "Sweet" },
  { id: 5, name: "Queso", category: "UwU" },
  { id: 6, name: "Arandanos", category: "Fruit" },
  { id: 7, name: "Maracuya", category: "Fruit" },
];

const productsGroup = products.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.category] = [...(r[a.category] || []), a];
  return r;
}, {});

function applySettings(settings) {
  return settings.filter((s) => s.display).map((s) => productsGroup[s.name]);
}

console.log(
  applySettings([
    {
      name: "Fruit",
      display: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Jam",
      display: false,
    },
  ])
);

console.log(
  applySettings([
    {
      name: "Fruit",
      display: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Sweet",
      display: true,
    },
    {
      name: "UwU",
      display: true,
    },
  ])
);
```

Comment: Includes `'Jam'` results.

Comment: @StackSlave adding a filter will help thanks for pointing that out

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. This is very inefficient because it keeps making copies the accumulator on each *reduce* loop to create the intermediate *group* object, then uses *filter* and *map* to get the required output.

Comment: @RobG  sometimes making copies can save lots of processing, again and again, all depends on the scenario, based on the scenario the code can perform best or worst. you are right, a good answer should explain OP. Thanks, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty quick, because it `continue`s on to the next iteration without executing the inner loop when `display` is `false`:

```js
var products = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Chocolate', category: 'Sweet'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Almendras', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Nueces', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Mermelada', category: 'Jam'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Alfajor', category: 'Sweet'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Queso', category: 'UwU'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Arandanos', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 7, name: 'Maracuya', category: 'Fruit'}
];

let settings = [
    {
        name: 'Fruit',
        display: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Jam',
        display: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Sweet',
        display: true
    },
    {
        name: 'UwU',
        display: true
    }
];
function sortProducts(){
  const r = [];
  let i = -1;
  for(let s of settings){
    if(!s.display){
      continue;
    }
    i++;
    for(let o of products){
      if(s.name === o.category){
        if(r[i]){
          r[i].push(o);
        }
        else{
          r.push([o]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
console.log(sortProducts());
```